# Recursively replace value with $path in JQ

Tags: json, jq

Assuming that  i have a complex JsonObject

```json
{
  "parent": {
    "name": "value",
    "child": {
      "child_value1": "value",
      "child_value2": "value",
      "child_value3": ["value1","value2"],
      "child_value4": {
         "child_child_value1":"value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to replace the value of each key, with the name of key prefixed with $

```json
{
  "parent": {
    "name": "$name",
    "child": {
      "child_value1": "$child_child_value1",
      "child_value2": "$child_child_value2",
      "child_value3": ["$child_child_value3_0","$child_child_value3_1"],
      "child_value4": {
         "child_child_value1":"$child_child_value4_child_child_value1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do it recursively?

**EDIT**

This is the currently configuration file that I am using

```json
{
  "apis": {
    "order": {
      "base_url": "$mapping_base_url"
    },
    "payment": {
      "base_url": "$admin_base_url"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "authentication": {
      "authProviders": true,
      "registration": false
    }
  },
  "availableLocales":["en","es"]
}
```

This is the result using the recomended jq expression:

`. |= reduce paths(strings) as $p (.; setpath($p; "$" + ($p | join("_"))))`

```json
{
  "apis": {
    "order": {
      "base_url": "$apis_order_base_url"
    },
    "payment": {
      "base_url": "$apis_payment_base_url"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "authentication": {
      "authProviders": true,
      "registration": false
    }
  },
  "availableLocales": [
    "$availableLocales_0",
    "$availableLocales_1"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
.parent |=
  reduce paths(strings) as $p (.;
    setpath($p; "$" + ($p | join("_")))
  )
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/U6aUeg3oLqb)</sup>

Comment: do you have any suggestions if my root object have more than one property?

Comment: @V You can try `map_values(reduce ...)`.

Comment: you mean `. |=
  map_values(reduce paths(strings) as $p (.;
    setpath($p; "$" + ($p | join("_")))
  ))` ? if so, doesn't work

Comment: I'll edit the post, so you can take a look what is my currently configuration

Comment: @V Check this out https://jqplay.org/s/MjB0vl8fEOf Is it what you want?

Comment: I can't thankyou enough for this. Truly appreciate